# Connecting to jira cloud using python

Tags: python, jira, jira-rest-api, python-jira

I am trying to connect jira cloud using REST API. This is my Python code for it:

```
pip install jira

from jira import JIRA

jiraOptions = {'server': "https:url"}

user = 'emailid'

apikey = 'api token'

server = 'https:url'

options = {
 'server': server
}
```

After this when I execute this line I get a connection error

`jira = JIRA(basic_auth=(user,apikey))`

> ConnectionRefusedError

I am not sure what has gone wrong and I tried finding the right syntax but I dont see what the problem is can anyone please help?

Comment: You're not getting a syntax error, so syntax isn't your problem. You're getting a `ConnectionRefused` error, which suggests that the URL you're using is pointing at a server that isn't running Jira on the port you're using in the URL. Since we don't know anything about your server, and you don't show the actual URL in your question, there's not much else we can say.

Comment: @larsks you mean I shall check whether my server is really running or not? Also I tried running the url in postman environment and there it did work perfectly well. Can it still be because of an issue in my server?

Comment: I'm still not really sure how to solve the issue can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Hey @Bobby I ran into some similar problems. I created this repo to use straight Python and the API to get most things done - https://github.com/dren79/JiraScripting_public
A lot of the basic functionality is in the helpers.py file, let me know if it helps.